# Set of almost integral elements is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $R^*$ be the set of all elements $s \in \operatorname{Quot}(R)$ that are almost integral over $R$. Show that $R^*$ is normal.

Edit: An element $s \in \operatorname{Quot}(R)$ is said to be almost integral over $R$ if there exists a nonzero $c \in R$ such that $cs^n \in R$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$. An integral domain $R$ is called normal if it is integrally closed in its field of fractions $\operatorname{Quot}(R)$.

There is a hint given:

For $s_, \ldots, s_{m-1} \in R^*$ show that there is a $c \in R \setminus \{0\}$ such that $cs \in R$ for all $s \in R[s_0, \ldots, s_{m-1}]$.

I'm not quite sure on how to show the hint and on how to use it after.

Comment: provide definitions

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez I edited it.

Comment: Please do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who answered the question, and rude to future readers who might find the answer(s) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the hint is easy. Just let $c_i \in R$ be such that $c_is_i^n \in R$ for all $n$ and let $c$ be the product of all the $c_i$.

Now take $s= p/q \in \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ integral over $R^*$ and let $s^n + r_{n-1}s^{n-1}+ \ldots + r_0=0$, where $r_i \in R^*$, and let $c$ be the one of the lemma. Then for any $k >n$, using the polynomial relation that satisfies $s^n$, $s^k$ can be written as
$$
f_{k,n-1}(r_0, \ldots , r_{n-1})s^{n-1}+ \ldots + f_{k,0}(r_0, \ldots , r_{n-1})
$$
where the $f_i$ are polynomials. Therefore, if $d=q^nc$,
$$
ds^k = cf_{k,n-1}(r_0, \ldots , r_{n-1})q^ns^{n-1}+ \ldots +cf_{k,0}(r_0, \ldots , r_{n-1}) \in R
$$
showing that $s \in R^*$